# Downsides of using static segments (pretty urls)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, routes

I'm playing around with the idea of using pretty urls ([static segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#static-segments)) to pass params to my controller.

http://example.com/miami/33131

```
match ':city/:zip', :to => 'events/#index'
```

It's working well so far but I'm trying to think of the downsides of doing this instead of the typical query string-type urls.

What are your thoughts about this?

Thanks,
Francis